# Amazon AWS SDK MediaConvert is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm creating a typescript application using the Amazon AWS SDK installed from NPM.  I can make calls using the AWS.S3 object fine, but am unable to use the AWS.MediaConvert:

```
var endpointPromise = new AWS.MediaConvert({apiVersion: '2017-08-29'})
    .describeEndpoints(params)
    .promise();
```

The error I receive at runtime is "TypeError: AWS.MediaConvert is not a constructor".  I can inspect the AWS object and can see a lot of properties, but MediaConvert is not one of them.

I assume it's because the package on npm is a subset of the full SDK (yet it has typescript definitions for MediaConvert).  Is it possible to get a full SDK from npm, or will have to build my own via https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/ and embed it in my app?

It won't have typescript definitions in it, which will make development more difficult.  Can I include the npm package and also the downloaded bundle without things messing up?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet, I hope it's gonna help you:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const mediaAWS = async function()
{
    try
    {
        const params = {};
        const media: AWS.MediaConvert = new AWS.MediaConvert({apiVersion: '2017-08-29'})
        const response: AWS.MediaConvert.DescribeEndpointsResponse = await media.describeEndpoints(params).promise();
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.error(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help solve the issue sorry.  I've found that if use: import MediaConvert from 'aws-sdk/clients/mediaconvert' then it does work, but using import * from 'aws-sdk' does not.  It's very strange.  I suspect it might be a webpack related issue.

Comment: did you try es6 syntax like: const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); ? Can you share your config file?

Comment: es6 syntax doesn't work either.  I will see if I can create a minimal setup to reproduce the issue.